# Coldfusion: conflicting cfdump statements

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a query l.q. l is var scoped:

```
var l = {};
```

If I dump l:

```
writeDump(var:l, abort:true);
```

I get [image: dump of l]

You can see that q (l.q) shows [undefined struct element]. However if I do:

```
writeDump(var:isQuery(l.q), abort:true);
```

I get yes as the output? Dumping l.q.recordCount returns 1.

If I dump l.q I get an error: **Error Type** java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : [N/A].

This is causing me quite a headache as on my website I get variables randomly disappearing like this all the time.

Any ideas of what could be going on here? CF9.0.1 Ent running on Windows Server 2005.

Comment: the name:value syntax isn't officially supported in ColdFusion, and you should use name=value syntax instead: writeDump(var=isQuery(l.q), abort=true);

Comment: I'm pretty sure colon syntax is supported in CF9. But either way this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like whatever is populating your l.q variable is not working correctly. How is l.q being populated?

If you're using l = {} as a "local" scope replacement - don't ColdFusion 9 already has a local scope inside of functions and you can dump it.

Comment: <cfquery name="l.q" ... CF9 does have an in built local scope, but old CF8 habits die hard. Either way it has the same effect.

Comment: I take it there's nothing special in the cfquery itself? Have you tried assigning the query to a variable of its own eg var thisQuery = '';

Comment: No just a normal select. I'm not sure I understand you suggestion? you mean var thisQuery = l.q? What would that accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Are these dumps in the same place?  Remember that if you execute a query that does not return anything (such as an update or delete) but use the name parameter, that variable will be set to undefined.  It sounds like this could be happening here.

Comment: The query definitely returns a result. Dumping the record count results in 1.